# Replace mysql result's one row's spaces into '-'

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo " {$row['id']}. ". "<a href=\"/load/{$row['id']}/{$row['name']}\">{$row['name']}</a> <br> ".
     "Music : {$row['lljhg2']} <br> ".
     "Video : {$row['description']} <br> ".
     "Song  : {$row['artist']} <br> ".
     "--------------------------------<br>";}
```

Some code Like this, I want `{$row['name']}` in `<a href=\"/load/{$row['id']}/{$row['name']}\">` I want this row results all spaces replaced by dash ('-').

If the result is:

> Prince Reoy from USA

I want to print this:

> prince-reoy-from-usa

Is it possible?

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You wanted to say that PDO is more useful than mysql? But, I know nothing about it!

Comment: Not more useful, just better. The `mysql_*` API will be removed and one day all of your queries will stop working. There are links in the comment which show you how to use PDO.

Comment: do you want to replace them in a select query, or replace them in your table forever? those are 2 different animals altogether

Comment: I just want them as they are in the table.  but, output with space replaced by dash

Comment: You're trying to glue the data from the columns together? Or is there one column with words that you're trying to glue together?

Comment: OPPS! No, See What i'm trying to say.. $row["name"] What this is I don't really sure. IT just show the result of that tables one print result. But, I want to use that as a get variable in URL so, I need all space removed from that result so that the URL can be user Friendly. But, I'm really can't understand what to do.

Comment: If you don't understand, how can you explain it to us so we can help you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

either use this query

```
select lcase(replace(name, ' ', '-')) from table_name
```

or this php code

```
strtolower(' ', '-', str_replace($row['name']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) which will add the "glue" (the '-') between pieces of the array to make a string. Then you can lower the case of the string all at once with [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
$row_data = strtolower(implode('-', $row));
echo $row_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace spaces with dashes, and make the whole string lower case:

`strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $row['name']))`

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: OK , I'm trying this.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: sorry, replaced the "try this" with something better.

Comment: "Song URL : {strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $row['name']))}{$row['description']} <br> ". 

I used like this but, My page is Showing blank. Can You Please, tell me why?

Comment: This one will work: "Song URL : ".strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $row['name']))."{$row['description']} <br> ". The braces will only work when directly dealing with variables, but not on function results.

Comment: OPPS! No, See What i'm trying to say.. $row["name"] What this is I don't really sure. IT just show the result of that tables one print result. But, I want to use that as a get variable in URL so, I need all spaced removed from that result so that the URL can be user Friendly. But, I'm really can't understand what to do.

Comment: Well, `strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $row['name']))` does exaclty this: removes whites and makes the string lower case. You can use it as a get value. 

BUT, if you want to use it as a key to find a database record, that alone won't work. What most devs do is to append the record ID to the normalized string, like this: 

http://example.com/artists/88491_prince-reoy-from-usa

Then you have a semi-friendly URL. The PHP script will have to explode the parameter, getting the number before the underscore, which is the record ID, throwing away the normalized string after the underscore.